# Cannot install Qt postgreSQL driver

Tags: postgresql, qt

I'm posting here with the hopes that someone will be kind enough to help me. Just to clarify, I'm sort of a newb, so I'd be really grateful if you give more details to your explanations.

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit, QT 5.9.1, PostgreSQL is 9.6.3 version.

I'm working on a project, where I need to get a postgresql database running and connect it to the code I'm doing right now. Unfortunately, when I try to install the driver, I run into all kinds of problems. I've been reading on threads on sites, but they are outdated and some folders do not match, which my first problem arises. For some reason I cannot get qmake to work, even though I edit the path in the variables.

I tried running the commands from here.

```
cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ps
ql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/psql/include" "LIBS+=C:/psql/lib/ms/libpq.lib" psql.pro
nmake
```

Basically my folders don't aren't 100% as the guide, also I don't have a libpq.lib file

On my final attempt I tried the following:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/PostgreSQL/pg96/include" "LIBS+=C:/PostgreSQL/pg96/lib/libpq.lib"
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have PostgreSQL installed so you have `libpq.lib` and `libpq.dll`. You cannot compile the Qt PostgreSQL driver without these. You'll also need to find the `include` directory for your PostgreSQL install, the one that contains `libpq-fe.h`.

Then determine the paths to those. Set the `PATH` to include the directory with `libpq.dll`. Set `LIBS` to include the directory with `libpq.lib`. And set the `INCLUDEPATH` to include the directory with `libpq-fe.h`.

You'll probably need to do this within a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" or run `vcvarsall.bat` fist, too, so qmake can find Visual Studio.